# How do I remove the “Cancel” option from the Draw button on the Leaflet.draw plugin?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, leaflet, web-deployment, leaflet.draw

As seen in the image below, I’d like to remove the option to cancel a drawing. Here’s my code:

Comment: you can use css style , inspect class or id put just display:none

Comment: would I have to do all that in the main leaflet.css file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With that code you can remove the "cancel" button on all shapes:

```
L.DrawToolbar.prototype.getActions = function (handler) {
        return [
            {
                enabled: handler.completeShape,
                title: L.drawLocal.draw.toolbar.finish.title,
                text: L.drawLocal.draw.toolbar.finish.text,
                callback: handler.completeShape,
                context: handler
            },
            {
                enabled: handler.deleteLastVertex,
                title: L.drawLocal.draw.toolbar.undo.title,
                text: L.drawLocal.draw.toolbar.undo.text,
                callback: handler.deleteLastVertex,
                context: handler
            }
      
        ];
    }
```

Original code: [Doc](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.draw/blob/d5dd11781c2e07f9e719308e504fe579000edf54/src/draw/DrawToolbar.js#L74)

Also you can allow the cancel button for handlers when you add a if and test if the correct handler is passed.

PS: For a newer "leaflet-draw" you can use [Leaflet-Geoman](https://github.com/geoman-io/leaflet-geoman)

Comment: This is really late notice, but thanks so much! This is exactly what I needed :)